# maven plugin run only if user preference

Tags: java, apache, maven, maven-3

Is there a generic way to do this for any maven plugin - run based on user preference/ disable it based on a property file?

Have a properly working maven plugin using com.mysema.querydsl, now want to change is so it only runs if a particular flag/ command line options is provided.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            //executions
            <configuration>
                <jdbcDriver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbcDriver>

                <jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://myurlk:port/db</jdbcUrl>
                <jdbcUser>id1</jdbcUser>
                <jdbcPassword>ccc</jdbcPassword>
                <packageName>com.sample</packageName>
                <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</targetFolder>
                <schemaPattern>APP</schemaPattern>
                    //goal prefix here?
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>${mysql.driver.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Tried to add

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                 <id>execution1</id>
                  <phase>test1</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>export</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

    and a goal prefix       
                                 <goalPrefix>mysema1</goalPrefix>
```

But not working. Want a way so this plugin is not run when we do a default

> mvn clean install

But need to add another flag to make it run?
Using Apache Maven 3.0.4

Comment: Is there a generic way to do this for any maven plugin - run based on user pref/ disable it based on a property file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a profile, add the plugin definition into the profile and add a property trigger for the profile like this:

```
<project>
  ...

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>profile-id</id>
        <activation>
          <property>
            <name>myProperty</name>
          </property>
        </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            ...
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</project>
```

When you build yout project with `mvn clean install` the plugin will not be executed, when you build your project with `mvn clean install -DmyProperty` or `mvn clean install -Pprofile-id` your plugin will be executed. In the second case the property activation trigger for the profile is obsolete.

Comment: thank you. beats deleting the section / remembering not to commit

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to put the plugin execution into a Maven profile? There are several triggers to enable a profile for a build (e.g. OS, Java version, property value or the profile id itself on the command line).
See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html for more details.

Comment: I'd also suggest to put the conditional execution of the plugin into a profile.

Comment: lots to read thru. do you have a simple get started set of instructions? just want that a plugin (see question) does not run by default, unless there is a specific command line flag? i see its there but lost on how to get it to work in easy steps